# Error in Flow - Update Element

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I have a bulkified flow which updates the user record. The error specifically occurs in a FastUpdate element which updates the user records stored in a SObjectCollectionVariable.

**Error string:**

> **FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR| Argument must be a big decimal**
>   java.lang.Integer|FlowRecordUpdate|UpdateUserRecords 
>   Error executing
>   flow: Update_User_Fields An unhandled fault has occurred in this
>   flow
> An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.
>   Please contact your system administrator for more information.

Plz let me know if there are any pointers to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: I raised this to salesforce support. Tier 2 team looked at this and have escalated it to Tier 3 support.

Comment: Hmmm getting this as well, will let you know if i find the answer.

Comment: I've raised a case also, 11950519. My use case is with Account btw.